# How introduce a company in a letter?

Tags: grammatical-number

I am writing a formal letter. How should I write it properly? I was wondering if someone could help me with the following context:

> **A)** We x company has it's office in (the location address of the office)... 
>   **B)** We x company have our office in (the location address of the office)...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, I have to point out a mistake:

- **it's:** a contraction of *it is*.  (Sometimes also a contraction for *it has*, but you should consider that kind of usage to be informal and not quite proper.)
- **its:** possessive form of *it*.

You need *its*, not *it's*.

---

Since the subject of the sentence is "We", the second form is more appropriate.  You should separate the company name using commas:

> We, *x* Company, have our office in (the address of the office)…

You could also refer to your own company in the third person:

> *x* Company has its office in (the address of the office)…

---

If the address is the name of a building, then use *in*.  If naming a specific floor, use *on*.  Otherwise, use *at*.  (The typical prepositions are: *in* a building; *on* a floor, *at* an address.)

> Our office is in the Empire State Building, 350 5th Ave., New York.
>
> Our office is on the 55th floor of the Empire State Building, 350 5th Ave., New York.
>
> Our office is at 350 5th Ave., Suite 5500, New York.

If that is confusing, you could always just say

> Our address is: Company *x*, *123 Fake St., Anywhere.*

---

As a side note: British English prefers to treat a company as plural, while American English treats a company as a singular entity.

Comment: Since the OP resides in Sweden, Br English being majorly followed there, I would recommend the expression to be limited to "X Company have its office in (address)". A company being a group of individuals.

Comment: @Invoker Is that true? I frequently hear that it is American English that is widely spoken in Sweden, mostly affected by TV.

Answer (score 0):

The correct choice between above two sentences would be :

> B) We X company *have* our office in (address)

Comment: Thanks Invoker. :) But I have seen many other formal letters in 'a' form. Of course the author of those letters had never been a native. That was why I decided to ask the natives to help me with it. I was wondering if any native could confirm Invoker's idea.

Comment: @A-friend We can use 'A' form in a sentence like *The company has its office in (address)* but if we associate **I/We** then we must use *have* instead of *has*